# how to pull changes from master branch into another branch (this branch created from master previously) in the root in git-tfs

Tags: tfs, git-tfs

I have two branch in git-tfs. one is master and other is QA, this branch is created from master previously. All the recent changes are in master. Now i want to get the changes from master to my QA branch. how to get that? I want to get done that from the browser.

Comment: What's the detail mean of the git-tfs in your above question? Are you talking about the `git-tfs` tool - -  a two-way bridge between TFS and git? Or just mean the git source control in TFS?

Comment: @Patrick-MSFT it is git source control in TFS.

Comment: Then you could create a pull request to achieve the merge in the browser.

Comment: Hi MarsRoverll, any update on this, have you solved it?

Comment: @Patrick-MSFT, thanks my problem is solved.

Answer (score 1):

If you are talking the `git-tfs` command tool, you could also manager merges with git-tfs.

> If you want, for example, to merge the branch `b1` in the trunk
>   `trunk`, you need that `b1` and `trunk` to be **entirely checked in
>   Tfs**. Once done, you could do the merge with git **as a normal merge
>   with 2 local git branches.** Then you have to check this commit into
>   Tfs with the command `rcheckin` and a merge changeset will be created
>   into Tfs.

More details please refer this tutorial *[git-tfs](https://github.com/git-tfs/git-tfs/blob/master/doc/usecases/manage_tfs_branches.md)* ,but it's not able to do this from the browser.

If you are just talking about the GIT source control in TFS, and want to get done that from the browser. The only way is creating a **pull request**. Detail step just follow this thread: [Create a pull request](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/git/tutorial/pullrequest)

Answer (score 0):

You will just have to synchronise the branch with the master and it will do, i.e in easier terms synchronisation of a branch means to merge the master into that branch. That's it!